# Project wont reflect changes on localhost

Tags: git, apache, phpmyadmin, localhost, sublimetext2

I am developing for phpmyadmin. I have forked the repository and set it up on my local machine. However when i make changes to the code, it doesnt reflect on localhost. I am using Sublime Text and using git too. When i view the code using vim or opening it from the explorer in gedit, i see that the code has indeed changed as i changed it using Sublime Text. But the localhost still wont show any changes. Whats wierd is that the changes arent reflected on closing the browser or the text editors, but on restarting the system. Why is this happening and how can i rectify it?

Comment: Sounds strange, like a bug in the file system or its access layer, never heard something like that. What kind of storage are you using for the files? And how is it accessed by the http server? What kind of system is that locally?

Comment: Ah, sorry, no! This is probably just a caching issue! Have a try making a "deep reload" in your browser, or switch off the cache in your browsers development console. Or add headers preventing the caching for development.

Comment: Oh jeez! that solved it. I had no clue that was happening. And this surprises me because I have never before encountered this scenario. Anyways, thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably just a caching issue! Have a try making a "deep reload" in your browser, or switch off the cache in your browsers development console. Or add headers preventing the caching for development.